# How to input non-alphabetic letters (such as Chinese, Japanese, Korean) in unix/linux console without X running

Tags: linux, unix, input-method-kit

How to input non-alphabetic letters without built-in input method tool (vim, emacs and so on)?

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Question may be appropriate for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.